# AWS Textract reading specific information using dotnet sdk C#

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-net, amazon-textract

I am trying to use amazon textract to get specific information from resume pdf file wheich is available in a local folder.

I am able to get the text using code below

sample code

```html
 using (var textractClient = new AmazonTextractClient(RegionEndpoint.APSouth1))
        {
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/pdfresume.pdf"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            await fileStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            await fileStream.FlushAsync();
           

            var analyzeDocumentRequest = new AnalyzeDocumentRequest()
            {
                Document = new Document { Bytes = memoryStream },
                FeatureTypes = new List<string> { "FORMS" } 
                //here i wish to pass many queries like "what is the email id"
            };

            var analyzeDocumentResponse = await textractClient.AnalyzeDocumentAsync(analyzeDocumentRequest);
            foreach(var blocks in analyzeDocumentResponse.Blocks)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(blocks.Text);
            }
 
        }
```

But my purpose is to get specific data using queries

as in php

```html
 'QueriesConfig' => [
        'Queries' => [  
            [
               
                'Text' => 'What is name' 
            ],
            [
 
                'Text' => 'What is email' 
            ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add "QUERIES" to the FeatureTypes, and then inject the query.

Something like:

```cs
 using (var textractClient = new AmazonTextractClient(RegionEndpoint.APSouth1))
        {
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/pdfresume.pdf"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            await fileStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            await fileStream.FlushAsync();
           
            Query query = new Query {
              Alias = "MyAlias",
              Text = "What is my name"
            }; 
            List<Query> queries = new List<Query>{ query };

            var analyzeDocumentRequest = new AnalyzeDocumentRequest()
            {
                Document = new Document { Bytes = memoryStream },
                FeatureTypes = new List<string> { "QUERIES" },
                QueriesConfig = new QueriesConfig{
                  Queries = queries
                };
            };

            var analyzeDocumentResponse = await textractClient.AnalyzeDocumentAsync(analyzeDocumentRequest);
            foreach(var blocks in analyzeDocumentResponse.Blocks)
            {
                if(blocks.BlockType.Value== "QUERY_RESULT")
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(blocks.Text);
            }
 
        }
```

Comment: Hi @Filippo, the code still retrieves all blocks. i just need specific info like name or email or phone

Comment: The output should return the Query Result object, with the reference of the block ids that contains the data matching your query: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/API_AnalyzeDocument.html

Comment: hi @Filippo, Thanks the solution worked. I have edited the code to just extract the query results. I have one more question, can we get the query against which the query result has generated

Comment: Yes, I've added in the snippet also the query Alias, you can find it referenced in the relative Block in the result

Comment: i am sorry, i didnt get. My purpose is to show the output as 
"question that i have asked": "Result"

Example "What is the name ": "John"

Comment: blocks.Query.Text, in the above example, returns "What is my name", or you can access through blocks.Query.Alias

Comment: unfortunately blocks.Query is null in the output

Comment: because you're reading only the QUERY_RESULT type. explore the docs better: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/API_AnalyzeDocument.html 
and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/API_Block.html

Comment: yes i get  blocks.Query.Text but to connect the query and qyery_result i dont have any link. if (blocks.BlockType.Value == "QUERY")
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(blocks.Query.Text + " : ");
                else if (blocks.BlockType.Value == "QUERY_RESULT")
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(blocks.Text);
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<br/>");

                }

This way i am getting. but if its sequential